# How to Listen to Vaadin component events in a JavaFX WebView?

Tags: java, javafx, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin21

I have created a form with Vaadin Flow (Vaadin version 21) with a save button. This form is then shown in a JavaFX WebView (Version 17.0.1) and now I want to listen to events in the form like save button from JavaFX, so I can update JavaFX parts of the application. I have seen examples like:

[How to retrieve components from HTML webview in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280174/how-to-retrieve-components-from-html-webview-in-javafx)

But they don't work since `doc.getElementById("xxx")` does not work at all and returns null. If I use the xpath method described there, I do get the button element, but then the adding the listener by calling the

```
((EventTarget) button).addEventListener("click", e -> doSomeAction(), false);
```

does not help. When I click the button the Vaadin listener works but the "javafx" listener does not get the event.

So my question is if there is a known solution for this Use Case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke Java methods from JavaScript with upcalls. It works by assigning a JavaScript object to a Java one:

```java
JSObject jso = (JSObject)webEngine.executeScript("window");

jso.setMember("java", new JavaObj());
```

Full example:

```java
public class JavaObj {
  public void myMethod() {
    ...
  }
}
```

```java
webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // Obviously...

webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldState, newState) -> {
  if(newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
    JSObject jso = (JSObject)webEngine.executeScript("window");

    jso.setMember("java", new JavaObj());
  }
});
```

```js
((EventTarget) button).addEventListener("click", e -> UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("java.myMethod()"), false);
```

More about upcalls [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/js-javafx.htm).

Comment: I don't see how this could change anything. I was wondering also the "window" and "java" you picked, are they just madeup thing or do they actually have to be set to those values?

Comment: `JSObject jso = (JSObject)webEngine.executeScript("window")` returns the JavaScript object `window` represented by a Java `JSObject`. `jso.setMember("java", new JavaObj())` adds a new object to `window`, that references back to a Java object, `new JavaObj()`. The choice of `window` is necessary, but the choice of `java` is arbitrary.

Comment: Hi, did this answer your question? Do you need more help?

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion, but it did not help. Right now I am busy with something else.

Comment: OK, now I got it to work as you wrote. Must be added that  in the vaadin code you have also to call the myMethod as a javascript call and not a java call as you wrote here.

Comment: @Keyhan Glad to hear it. What do you mean call `myMethod` as a JavaScript call? Do you mean instead of `java.myMethod()`, you used `webEngine.executeScript`?

Comment: In the vaadin code when you click the button you need to do UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("java.myMetho()")

Comment: You're right, that is a typo. Updating my post.

Comment: Ok, now it is done!